# FreeMind on Mac - how to get centre-page alignment when saving as PDF

Tags: pdf, format, mind-mapping

I'm creating a Test Management mind map, using my home Macbook. I'll be saving it as a PDF so I can present it at work.

Problem: When using the Export function and saving it as a PDF, it's saving at the very top of the document. Print Preview (before doing the Export) shows me it is displayed at the top of the page too.

How can I ensure it displays in the center of the page?

Comment: I came across this issue once recently.  I played around with it for a few minutes, but was in a rush.  I ended up just exporting the map as an image and pasting it into Word and then saving it as a PDF.

Comment: Thanks, surely it is possible, with so many other good and more complex features there, and I'm hardly asking for something obscure.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have found to get the map centered on the PDF page, albeit with quite a bit of space top and bottom, is to

1. Save as SVG
2. Open up SVG file in a browser, works well with Chrome for example
3. Right click on image and click Print
4. Adjust the margins before printing, that is, make the top margin much larger than usual until the map is centered.